# Can a save action be performed in a table method of Cakephp model?

Tags: php, cakephp

For example i have this in my controller:

```
public function add()
    {
        $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $bookmark = $this->Bookmarks->patchEntity($bookmark, $this->request->data);
            $bookmark->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Bookmarks->save($bookmark)) {
                $this->Flash->success('The bookmark has been saved.');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
        $tags = $this->Bookmarks->Tags->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('bookmark', 'tags'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmark']);
    }
```

Can a save action/method be done also in model table method?

Comment: Have you tried this code. If yes what error are you getting?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet,thought to ask if anyone has to see if it's possible.